# How to avoid Toshiba SSD S.M.A.R.T. value decrease just by calling Win32_DiskDrive?

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript, wmi, solid-state-drive

Recently I found S.M.A.R.T. wear leveler value of Toshiba SSD decrease just by calling `Win32_DiskDrive` of WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation).

All I want to do is just to monitor and log the connect/removal of disk drives (e.g. USB flash, SD card, external CD/DVD drives) every second. The customer's requirement is to monitor possible information leakage via these devices.

However, when I call `Win32_DiskDrive` via VBScript or PowerShell for various vendors' SSD, such as SanDisk, Micron (Crucial), Samsung and Toshiba, only Toshiba SSD's wear leveler S.M.A.R.T. 'AD' value keeps going down and lead to Toshiba disk utility or Windows disk alert popup.

I understand `Win32_DiskDrive` does *NOT write/read any data* on disk drives.

My question is how to call `Win32_DiskDrive` without affecting Toshiba SSD's wear leveler 'AD' value.

Affected Toshiba SSDs as follows.

- TOSHIBA_THNSNF128GMCS
- TOSHIBA_THNSNJ128GMCU
- TOSHIBA_THNSNS128GMCP

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.  Have you checked for firmware and/or device driver updates?

Comment: @Harry Johnston , thank you for your comment. Today I asked Toshiba technical support and got an answer. They say these SSDs write the response data into themselves when Win32_DiskDrive is called, so we should not call Win32_DiskDrive too frequently. They say this is the spec of these models.

Comment: OK, so the drives are buggy by design, that's unfortunate.  You might want to post that as an answer.  (You may have noticed that it was happening, but most software vendors wouldn't have had any reason to check.  So there's probably lots of software that uses Win32_DiskDrive, perhaps not once a second, but frequently enough to affect the life of those drives.  I wonder how often Windows itself does this?)

Comment: I would guess that Win32_DiskDrive translates into more than one I/O request to the drive. If so, then it may be that only one of the I/O requests actually affects the drive. For instance it may translate into obtaining mode page 80h and 83h (and possibly others), but maybe only 83h causes a drive write. If that's the case then u may be able to substitute an I/O request(s) for Win32_DiskDrive. U can use OSR's IRP tracker to see what I/O requests are actually being issued. You'd then write a Win32 program to issue IOCTLs that correspond to the I/O requests, interspersed with getting SMART info

Comment: BTW, a filter driver would be a much more robust method for checking for info leakage. It would see all I/O requests to the drive. A program exfiltrating info could time its writes to the drive (along with toggling the drive offline/online or similar) to avoid detection. Better still, and assuming there's not a business for removable media, the customer can physical disable USB ports, SD slots, etc, by filling with epoxy. Or some vendors allow ports to be disabled in the BIOS.

Comment: The Configuration Manager API and/or Setup API might also be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I conclude that this is Toshiba SSD bug in design, most probably in their firmware of SSD. I strongly hope Toshiba will release firmware update soon.

Thanks @Harry Johnston for your advice.

The main reason of this conclusion is that during my over 120 hours test of continuous `Win32_DiskDrive` call, I found clear difference of S.M.A.R.T. values between Toshiba's and other two vendors'.

Toshiba's wear level value 'AD' decreased by 25 from the default value 200 to 175, while *no* S.M.A.R.T. values of two other vendor SSDs changed at all except for temperature while the power on hours of each SSDs as follows.

Toshiba THNSNF128GCSS: 124 hours
SanDisk SDSSDHII240G : 829 hours
Crucial CT256MX100SSD1: 2705 hours

This means the youngest SSD is now wearing fastest on my PC by `Win32_DiskDrive` call test.

And thank @Χpẘ for your detail explanation of possible effects of calling Win32_DiskDrive and alternative ways for checking information leakage.

However, to tell the truth, now I have no choice other than calling `Win32_DiskDrive` because I'm not in the position that can change the design. This means all I can do is to decrease the number of `Win32_DiskDrive` calls per second.